# vscode: how to change the hotkey of 'replace' and 'next match'

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

In the replace mode of vscode:

[image]

The hotkeys of *'go to next match'* and *'replace'* are both `enter`.

I want to selectively replace some words.
For example, in the lower part of the image: I want to rename `hidden_dim' but not` hidden_dim_in`.

Hitting the key `enter` will **repeatedly do either *'go to next match'* or *'replace'***. How could I set different hotkeys for these two functions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inspired by @amordo's answer, I find an easier way to "go to next match" while replacing words in vscode:

**F3**

The F3-key is the default setting of vscode for finding next, which works properly during replacing.

[image]

Ps. the **Shift + Enter** short cut, doesn't help in this case. It will add a new line.[image]

Answer (score 2):

I've added a new shortcut to `keybindings.json` *Command Palette -> Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)*:

```
{
    "key": "shift+cmd+enter",
    "command": "editor.action.nextMatchFindAction",
    "when": "editorFocus && replaceInputFocussed"
}
```

Another way is to `Add Keybinding...` based on *'go to next match' (Find Next)* shortcut in `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts` and change it via UI.  [image]

Now using a new shortcut with *replace* window focused you go to the next match; press *enter* to replace that.[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've found a really simple way of doing this with no customization.  When the focus is on the find text box, hitting `enter` will go to the next match without applying any change however, when focus is in the replace text box hitting `enter` will make the change and go to the next match.  It is possible to switch focus between the two text boxes using `tab` and `shift + tab`.

Comment: He asked for a hotkey configuration not an alternative way actually

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Good Answer.  you save my day